# “new songs with the authority that their old songs had...”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Q. On that tour, you performed a number of excellent songs you've still never released. I'm thinking of titles like Traces, Love-Art Blues and Pushed It Over The End. What happened to those songs?
> A. Well they'll probably be out on the anthology too. Listen, ***if they'd had new songs with the authority that their old songs had***, we could've knocked off four and five of mine so that just the best two surfaced... That would have truly been CSN&Y. But it wasn't to be, so the record never came out.

“ if they'd had new songs with the authority that their old songs had, we could've knocked off four and five of mine so that just the best two surfaced...”

Hello, could anyone help me understand what he’s saying above?
I don’t understand what “with the authority” really means in this context.

Is he saying that if new songs were as good as their old ones, they would have put these new songs on the album instead of four or five of his songs?

Comment: "as good as the old ones" I think

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is what he's saying. The word *authority* has more to it, though.
In particular note definition 3b:

> b: convincing force
>
> *lent authority to the performance*

see
[1]: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/authority